# subtract 2 rows of same column for different status

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like below:

```
app_no    |       curr_time          updt_time         status
212461248 | 2016-04-30 20:26:54 |2016-05-04 08:36:17 |  Incomplete
212461248 | 2016-04-30 20:26:54 |2016-11-18 11:17:28 |  Error
212461248 | 2016-04-30 20:26:54 |2017-01-27 02:00:40 |  Refer
212461248 | 2016-04-30 20:26:54 |2017-08-12 23:59:02 |  Declined
212461251 | 2017-06-15 01:41:13 |2017-06-22 04:02:11 |  Error
212461251 | 2017-06-15 01:41:13 |2017-10-18 01:34:09 |  Declined
212461253 | 2016-06-21 00:56:23 |2016-06-24 11:44:17 |  Incomplete
212461253 | 2016-06-21 00:56:23 |2017-09-04 18:20:06 |  Error
```

I would like to get the time taken by each application to move from one status to another (from updt_time column)?

Ex: time take by 212461248 to move from incomplete to error, error to refer and refer to declined.

output should be like

```
status   time_taken
------  -----------
error     hh
refer     hh
declined  hh
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: please with values - I still don't get how you aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use window functions:

Let's try this

```
SELECT app_no, status, extract(epoch FROM (updt_time - lag(updt_time) OVER (PARTITION BY app_no ORDER BY updt_time))::interval) as time_taken
FROM your_table
```

More information about window functions can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).